# Node.js Heroku deployment language cannot be detected

Tags: node.js, heroku, yarnpkg

```
Counting objects: 64, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (58/58), done.
Writing objects: 100% (64/64), 541.82 KiB | 12.90 MiB/s, done.
Total 64 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to stockandtrack.
remote:
```

I have gotten the error above when trying to push my Node.js app to Heroku. I have verified that my `package.json` is in the root folder and have added the engine declaration to my `package.json`. I continue to receive this error. Below is my `package.json` and folder structure:

```
    {
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.4"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && yarn run start:prod || yarn run start:dev",
    "start:prod": "node server.js",
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"nodemon --ignore 'client/*'\" \"yarn run client\"",
    "client": "cd client && yarn run start",
    "install": "cd client && yarn install",
    "build": "cd client && yarn run build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "yarn run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

[image: File Structure]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are your root-level `package.json` and `yarn.lock` tracked by Git?

Comment: I just tested it and it is updating the package.json and yarn.lock on github. I am using a remote branch, could that be an issue with pushing to heroku?

Comment: What do you mean by "I am using a remote branch"?

Comment: I was not on the master branch. I solved this by using git push heroku mybranchname:master